# Why are my visits logged under differing IPs?

Tags: linux, apache-httpd, logs

I have seven websites hosted with the same provider, all part of the same hosting plan. Yesterday I visited all my sites one after another and looked at the Apache access logs. At that time, several What-is-your-IP? sites gave my IP as (I have anonymized the last parts for this question):

```
IPv4 84.143.222.xxx
IPv6 2003:df:972e:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx:xxx
```

In my logs, my visits where registered with the following IPs (IPs are anonymized in the logfiles due to European data protection laws):

```
2003:df:9700::    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.13; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
212.227.221.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A
217.160.152.0     Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A
```

How can that be?

It *looks* as if someone else must have visited my sites. But I have visited my sites in a certain order, and several sites are missing from the logs if I only look at the visits from the one IPv6. If I add the visits from the two IPv4 addresses, the pattern of my visits is complete.

Also, my sites are not connected together for visitors in any way. There are no links between them, they have different topics, and different persons and addresses are given in the imprint and TOS. For anyone except myself (and the hosting provider) they must appear completely unrelated. And yet the two IPv4 visits where to all of my seven sites.

It is extremely unlikely that anyone would know all these sites belong together and visit them all one after another at the same time I visit them in the exact same order.

So what's going on?

Host is Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
Kernel is 3.16.0-ui18135.21-uiabi1-infong-amd64

Comment: Are you using the same web browser when you visit the various sites?

Comment: @andydalton I have visited my sites with Firefox (the IPv6 useragent string). I have **not** used Safari for part of my visits, as the IPv4 useragent string suggests.

Comment: Please visit [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to merge your accounts so you can respond to comments.

Comment: If you used Firefox for all your visits, then it seems very unlikely to me that all of those logs were triggered by you.

Comment: This is more likely a NET issue, can you compaere `traceroute what-my-ip` and `traceroute my-web-site` somehow your IP is rewrite along the way. Ip are not unchanging when travelling in world wild wed. (wed in no longer wide, but wild as in world wild west).

Comment: Interesting comment, @Archemar. `traceroute www.mywebsite.com` shows that the second IP in my question (212.227.221.0) is the last server on the traceroute, which is a server of my hosting provider (ae-10-0.bb-a.bap.rhr.de.oneandone.net). And the third IP in my question (217.160.152.0) is actually the IP of my domain. So for some reason my IP is being replaced with IPs of my webhost when I call my website. But the question remains: Why and how does that happen? And how reliable does that make the rest of my logs?

Comment: you say “IPs are anonymized in the logfiles” maybe that is the reason. Of did you change them, before posting?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the hosting company, is port-forwarding, so save on IP addresses. We (that is everyone) ran out of IP addresses a few years back.